# Custom QGIS Processing Tool Fails to Copy Features

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm creating a custom QGIS Processing plugin. I've created a tool that is basically supposed to copy features from an input PostGIS layer to a new PostGIS layer. My routine runs without errors and successfully creates the new table in the database, but when I load the new layer into QGIS no features are copied over. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Code is copied below. At this point I'm testing by simply copying the feature geometries, although in the future I would also be copying attribute information.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceURI, QgsVectorLayerImport, QGis, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry

import processing
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithmExecutionException import GeoAlgorithmExecutionException
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterString
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterTableField
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterBoolean
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterSelection

from processing.tools import dataobjects, vector
from processing.algs.qgis import postgis_utils
from dbutils import LayerDbInfo


class StandardizeRoadNetwork(GeoAlgorithm):
    TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
    ROADS_LAYER = 'ROADS_LAYER'

    def defineCharacteristics(self):
        self.name = 'Create standardized road layer'
        self.group = 'Algorithms for vector layers'
        self.addParameter(ParameterString(self.TABLE_NAME,
            self.tr('Name of table to be created'), optional=False))
        self.addParameter(ParameterVector(self.ROADS_LAYER,
            self.tr('Roads layer'), [ParameterVector.VECTOR_TYPE_LINE], optional=False))

    def processAlgorithm(self, progress):
        # Retrieve the values of the parameters entered by the user
        tableName = self.getParameterValue(self.TABLE_NAME).strip().lower()
        inLayer = dataobjects.getObjectFromUri(self.getParameterValue(self.ROADS_LAYER))

        roadsDb = LayerDbInfo(inLayer.source())
        dbHost = roadsDb.getHost()
        dbPort = roadsDb.getPort()
        dbName = roadsDb.getDBName()
        dbUser = roadsDb.getUser()
        dbPass = roadsDb.getPassword()
        dbSchema = roadsDb.getSchema()
        dbType = roadsDb.getType()
        dbSRID = roadsDb.getSRID()
        try:
            db = postgis_utils.GeoDB(host=dbHost,
                                     port=dbPort,
                                     dbname=dbName,
                                     user=dbUser,
                                     passwd=dbPass)
        except postgis_utils.DbError, e:
            raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException(
                self.tr("Couldn't connect to database:\n%s" % e.message))

        # create new table, starting with new fields
        fieldList = [
            {'name': 'id', 'pgtype': 'serial'},
            {'name': 'road_name', 'pgtype': 'text'}
        ]
        dbFields = []
        for f in fieldList:
            dbFields.append(postgis_utils.TableField(f['name'],f['pgtype']))
        db.create_table(tableName,
                        dbFields,
                        pkey='id',
                        schema=dbSchema)
        db.add_geometry_column(tableName, dbType, schema=dbSchema,
                               geom_column='geom', srid=dbSRID)
        db.create_spatial_index(tableName, schema=dbSchema, geom_column='geom')

        # set up the new table's uri and get new object
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        uri.setConnection(dbHost, str(dbPort), dbName, dbUser, dbPass)
        uri.setDataSource(dbSchema, tableName, 'geom', 'id')
        outLayer = dataobjects.getObjectFromUri(uri.uri(),forceLoad=True)

        # iterate features and add to new table
        outFields = outLayer.dataProvider().fields()
        inGeom = QgsGeometry()
        for feature in vector.features(inLayer):
            outFeat = QgsFeature(outFields)
            inGeom = feature.geometry()
            outFeat.setGeometry(inGeom)
            outLayer.addFeature(outFeat)
            del outFeat
        outLayer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: I can't see where you start editing... you only commit changes without start editing session